# Ext JS Grid Panel Height Property

Tags: extjs, grid

I'm creating a grid using Ext JS. I need to increase the height of the grid panel automatically with the increase of the number of rows in the grid. Which property of Ext JS grid can be set to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't specify a value to the height property, and that's all.

Try it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bnl

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

// Don't specify the height when creating the grid
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```